# Android App from Visual Studio is not running on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android, mobile-application

I have written an android application in Visual Studio 2015. While Trying to run that application on Emulator i am getting below on my output screen:

```
1>Starting deploy 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone ...
1>Starting emulator 5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone ...
1>Validating emulator arguments...
1>Determining if emulator is already running...
1>Preparing virtual machine...
1>Launching emulator...
1>Emulator launched successfully.
```

Any help how I can run my application on emulator ? 
[image: This is How my emulator is looking like]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if your application is compiled AND deployed?

Comment: @Ben: its getting build successfully, but not any sign of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this issue:

1. Go to regedit.exe.
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android.
3. Change the SDK path to my Xamarin Mono Android SDK folder.
4. The path originally was C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
   then I changed to
   C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK
5. It worked :)